# PowerShell Approved Verbs for "Archive" and "Unarchive" of Data Items

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have data that supports being Archived and Unarchived but none of the [Approved Verbs for PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-5.1) for data management or resource lifecycle seem to be a good fit.

Technically, the relevant data items are actually available over RESTful API and are referenced by ID. The Cmdlets I'm building speak to said API.

EDIT: These data items are more accurately described as records with the act of archiving being some form of recategorisation or relabelling of said records as being in an archived state.

Which verbs are most appropriate and what are some of the implementation factors and considerations that should be taken into account when choosing?

Comment: PowerShell actually has cmdlets for  ... `Compress-Archive` and `Expand-Archive`.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not actually creating file archives, I'm creating a PowerShell Module which speaks to a RESTful API.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. You could simply use a prefix for your API/TargetSystem name. So it would `Compress-ApiArchive` and `Expand-ApiArchive` then.  ;-)

Comment: Also you could just make it `Get` and `Set`. `Get-ArchiveState XY` and `Set-ArchiveState` or e.g. `Set-ApiItem -Id -Archive`. It really depends what archive represents in this context. It's mainly about what you'd expect from cmdlets and nobody is forcing you to abide by it.

Comment: @Olaf Except it isn't doing any compression or expanding, it's recategorising a data item in an archived state.

Comment: @Seth I think you may be right, others appear to do this as well, it's just my Cmdlet names are getting a tad long and already have so many Sets and Gets, was hoping to utilise the Approved Verb vocabulary a bit more so I didn't have so many Sets, Gets and Invokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this comes down to user-experience (user using said Cmdlets) versus actual-implementation. The [Approved Verbs for PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) article refers mostly to the actual-implementation when describing verbs, not so much the user-experience of those using Cmdlets. I think choosing PowerShell Verbs based on actual implementation, instead of abstracting that away and focusing on the common-sense user-experience, is the way the Approved PowerShell Verb list should be used.

> Set (s): **Replaces data on an existing resource** or creates a resource that contains some data...
>
> Get (g): Specifies an action that retrieves a resource. This verb is paired with Set.

Although the user maybe archiving something, they may only actually be changing a label or an archive-bit on the resource. In my case, the 'Archiving' is actually just a  flag on a row on a backend database, meaning, it is *replacing data on an existing resource*, so `Set-ArchiveState` (or equivalent) as [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6590026) suggested is the most appropriate here.

> New vs. Set
>
> Use the New verb to create a new resource. Use the Set verb to modify an existing resource, optionally creating it if it does not exist, such as the Set-Variable cmdlet.
>
> ...
>
> New (n): Creates a resource. (The Set verb can also be used when creating a resource that includes data, such as the Set-Variable cmdlet.)

I think `New` would only be applicable if you are creating a new resource based off of the old ones, the new resource representing an archived copy. In my use-case, it's Archival of a resource is represented by a flag, I am changing data on an existing resource primarily, thus, `New` isn't suitable here.

> Publish (pb): Makes a resource available to others. This verb is paired with Unpublish.
>
> Unpublish (ub): Makes a resource unavailable to others. This verb is paired with Publish.

There is an argument to be made that, if Archiving/Unarchiving restricts availability of the resource, `Publish`/`Unpublish` would be appropriate but I think this negatively impacts the user-experience even more than `Set`/`Get` does by using terminology in an uncommon way.

> Compress (cm): Compacts the data of a resource. Pairs with Expand.
>
> Expand (en): Restores the data of a resource that has been compressed to its original state. This verb is paired with Compress.

This is quite implementation specific and I think would only be suitable if the main purpose of the Archive/Unarchive action is for data compression and not for resource lifecycle management.

Answer (score 1):

`New-DataArchive` and `Remove-DataArchive`

Not sure of the particulars of the underlying API, but often there's a POST (new) and a DELETE (remove).

I'm also a big fan of adding `[Alias]`s when there's not a great match.  For example, I was recently working in a git domain where `Fork` is a well-known concept, so I picked the "closest" approved verb, but added an alias to provide clarity (aliases can be whatever you want)

```
function Copy-GithubProject {
    [Alias("Fork-GithubProject")]
    [CmdletBinding()]
```